# Vue js how call method defined in same component from another method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

I have a vue module which i have some methods defined, method1,method2, method3 ecc,

```
methods: {
          method1 : async function() { ... },
          method2 :  function() { ... },
          method3 :  function() { ... },
          showMessage : function(message) { ... }
}
```

i have added a showMessage function at the end of my methods list:

really trivial:

```
showMessage: function(message){
           alert(message);
}
```

but the problem is that i cannot able to recall from another methods of the module, if i try to recall for example from method3 i use this.showMessage("somethings") or showMessage("somethings "), but i have error :

Uncaught ReferenceError: showMessage is not defined

Comment: there a helper called `mixin` . You can take a look at vue docs

Comment: There should be no problem with `this.showMessage()` so if that doesn't work, something else is wrong.

Comment: How about provide a full demo?

Answer (score -1):

The problem shouldn't occur if you're calling showMessage from the component where it is defined. However, if you're calling it from some other component you first need some way to have that method in that component. The best way to share the same code between components while avoiding duplication is to create a mixin.

You can read about it here (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)